SQL Query to group data without using cursor
I have the following table:



Category
Product
Date
Price




C1
P1
01/01/2024
1


C1
P2
01/01/2024
2


C1
P3
01/01/2024
3


C1
P1
01/02/2024
4


C1
P2
01/02/2024
5


C1
P3
01/02/2024
6


C1
P1
01/03/2024
7


C1
P2
01/03/2024
8


C1
P3
01/03/2024
9


C2
P4
01/01/2024
10


C2
P5
01/01/2024
11


C2
P6
01/01/2024
12


C2
P4
01/02/2024
13


C2
P5
01/02/2024
14


C2
P6
01/02/2024
15


C2
P4
01/03/2024
16


C2
P5
01/03/2024
17


C2
P6
01/03/2024
18



I would like to create a summary of this table as per the following format:



Category
Date
Price




C1
01/01/2024
15.38  [formula (1+2+3) * 100/Sum(1+2+3+10+11+12)... i.e. sum of C1 category's data where date = 01/01/2024 .. divided by sum of all category's data where date = 01/01/2024]


C1
01/02/2024
25  [formula (4+5+6) * 100/Sum(4+5+6+14+15+16)... i.e. sum of C1 category's data where date = 01/02/2024 .. divided by sum of all category's data where date = 01/02/2024]



I can do this using a cursor but wondering if it is possible to do this using a SQL query using group by clause.

Yes, it is possible.

Your sample data doesn't seem to match your expected results, you seem to have the rows off by one.

You can use normal aggregation, and then use a window function on top of that
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.Category,
      t.Date,
      SUM(t.Price) AS TotalPrice,
      SUM(SUM(t.Price)) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Date) AS TotalForAll,
      SUM(t.Price) * 100 / SUM(SUM(t.Price)) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Date) AS [Percent]
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.Category,
      t.Date
) t
WHERE t.Category = 'C1';

db<>fiddle

thanks for the answer, learnt something new :)

You can use over partition by statement like this,

select Category,Date,
(SUM(Price) * 100.0) / SUM(SUM(Price)) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) AS Price
from your_table
group by Category,Date 
order by Category,Date;

